# Help binding command parameter to relative source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, commandbinding

I have a `ListBox` that I have added a `ContextMenu` to. I want one of the items in the `ContextMenu` to be bound to a command and I want the parameter passed to that command to be the currently selected item of the `ListBox` control. Here's my xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="selectedVascularBeds"             
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserSelectedVascularBeds}"                    
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
         dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"            
         DisplayMemberPath="VascularBedName">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveSelectedVascularBedCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                         Mode=FindAncestor,
                                         AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                                         Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

This `ListBox` is part of a user control that is bound to a view model object. My command method on the underlying object gets called but the parameter passed in is always null.

I have tested changing the binding of the `CommandParameter` to simply `{Binding}` which results in the user control's data context being passed into my method - so I know that the command is working and passes parameters correctly.  I just can't seem to get the correct binding to access the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem` property.

Help?

Answer (score 3):

the context menu is not a descendant of the list box.  try an element name binding instead

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveSelectedVascularBedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=selectedVascularBeds, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ElementName binding also didn't work, the parameter was still null and I found an error in the console output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=selectedVascularBeds'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type
>   'Object')

Searching for that error lead me to this link though and it looks like the Context menu is different and I can't achieve what I want the way I'm going about it.

[ElementName Binding from MenuItem in ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu)