# Is it possible to disable ContextMenu when there's no item in the ListView or no item's selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu

I've used the following method:

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove"
        Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

provided by blindmeis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082162/context-menu-for-removing-items-in-listview), for creating and binding `ContextMenu` and it works fine if I first select an item and then right click. If I, however, do not select any item and click anywhere in `ListView` it still appears and invoke the command with `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the `ContextMenu` on the `ListViewItem` instead of the `ListView`.

This will ensure that the `ContextMenu` will only display when there is a ListViewItem available. And if the item isn't selected, it will be when the user right-clicks on it.

The only trick here is to deal with a `DataContext` issue in the `ContextMenu`. That is done by setting the `Tag` property of the `ListViewItem` to the `DataContext` of the `ListView`. This will allow the `ContextMenu` to bind to the `RemoveItem` command.

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
    Width="200"
    Height="300"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.RemoveItem}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Header="Remove" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move your `ContextMenu` to the Resources, then apply it to the `ListView`'s `ContextMenu` in a `DataTrigger`, based on whether the `SelectedItem` is `null` or not:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">

        <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                  Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="itemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                        Value="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemsListView}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                                Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This also works. It'd be nice if I could accept both answers as solutions to my problem.