# Context menu with binding on name

Tags: wpf, data-binding, icommand

I'm trying to bind element by name to MenuItem in ContextMenu. Element to binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ATCheckerView.TestsPropagate"
         x:Name="TestPropagateRoot" ...
```

Working version:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SchemTemplate">
            <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=TestPropagateRoot, Path=DataContext.vclient.OpenInViewer}" />               
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Non-working:

```
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SchemTemplate">                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding path}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=TestPropagateRoot}"
                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=TestPropagateRoot, Path=DataContext.vclient.OpenInViewer}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617122/wpf-menuitem-command-binding-to-elementname-results-to-system-windows-data-error?rq=1) is a similar question and a good answer which show some ways how to handle contextmenu binding.

btw is use PlacementTarget Binding most time, e.g.

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding path}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Test"
                              Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.vclient.OpenInViewer, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
```

EDIT: {x:Reference TestPropagateRoot} may also an option if you using .net4.0

Comment: DataContext of TextBlock and ContextMenu and MenuItem initially the same. So your Command's binding does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SchemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding path}" 
                       Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:TestsPropagate}}}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Открыть для просмотра"
                                  Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.vclient.OpenInViewer, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />                                    
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```