# How do I reuse item children via a style in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF submenu that I want to reuse in a few places in my XAML. It's a collection of eight `<MenuItem>` elements with some complicated bindings that I don't want to copy/paste. However, the holder is different in each case: in one place the parent is a `<Menu>`, in another place the parent is a `<MenuItem>` in a `<ContextMenu>`.

I've been experimenting with `<Setter Property="Items">` in my `<Style>` but I think maybe I'm on the wrong track.

To make it concrete, I'm trying to reduce the code duplication from something like this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Details"    IsCheckable="True" ... />
    <MenuItem Header="List"       IsCheckable="True" ... />
    <MenuItem Header="Thumbnails" IsCheckable="True" ... />
    ...
</Menu>
...
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="View">
        <MenuItem Header="Details"    IsCheckable="True" ... />
        <MenuItem Header="List"       IsCheckable="True" ... />
        <MenuItem Header="Thumbnails" IsCheckable="True" ... />
        ...
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

You'll need to create the following collection in your resource dictionary:

```
<Collections:ArrayList x:Key="MenuItems" x:Shared="false">
    <MenuItem Header="Details" />
    <MenuItem Header="List" />
    <MenuItem Header="Thumbnails" />
</Collections:ArrayList>
```

You'll need to add the following namespace:

```
xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
```

...

And then just use the collection:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{StaticResource MenuItems}" />
```

...

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="View" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MenuItems}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Aha, that sounds great. However, it breaks all of my IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=...,Path=...}" constructs in the repeated MenuItems

Comment: Could you post the whole binding expression? It'd be easier knowing what the differences are between the bindings on each menu.

Comment: Here's one. The others are very similar. "thisControl" is the enclosing user control.            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=thisControl,Path=FilesView, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static my:FilesViewType.Details}}"
                      Header="{Binding Source={x:Static my:LocalizedStrings.MenuItemDetails}}" />

Comment: To clarify: the localization binding is working fine. But the IsChecked binding stopped working when I switched to the ArrayList approach. Thanks much

Comment: I would expect the bindings to work for the first case (plain Menu control), but not for the second (ContextMenu) because ContextMenu is not part of the same visual tree. 
Take a look at these questions. The first approach worked for me, but if you rather not change the code behind, then try the second link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617122/wpf-menuitem-command-binding-to-elementname-results-to-system-windows-data-error

Comment: Excellent. I had to do the following, but it worked. `foreach (object item in Resources["MenuItems"] as ArrayList)                NameScope.SetNameScope(item as DependencyObject, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));`

Comment: Oh, also: I had to change x:Shared to true because otherwise the newly instantiated MenuItems lost their NameScope.

Comment: Nope, I take it back. x:Shared=true broke everything. I'm back to square one... I can't get the namescope to stick.