# Binding a ContextMenu item's "IsEnabled" to a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a button to a context menu item that is represented by a NotifyIcon?

When I push the menu item, it starts a method that disables my `btnSave`. In that case, I would like to "turn off" the MenuItem too. I attempted it this way, but it's not working:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="NotifierContextMenu" Placement="MousePoint">
        <MenuItem Header="Start" Click="start_timer" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=btnSave, Path=IsEnabled}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem stems from a `ContextMenu` not existing within the visual tree, so `ElementName` bindings will be unsuccessful, unless you take some additional steps to correct the Name Scope, or resolve the `DataContext` to the visual tree.

Most of the techniques are covered fairly comprehensively in this answer: [ElementName Binding from MenuItem in ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu).

I've had success in the past with binding to a named element by reference, in your case, that would look something like this:

```
    <MenuItem Header="Start" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Source={x:Reference btnSave}}"
              Click="btnSave_Click"/>
```

Comment: Glad it helped, I'd definitely give that other answer a read for some alternatives if you have some spare time =D